# Build flash apps only using actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

Is it possible to make flash applications only using ActionScript? I can't buy the actual Adobe Flash. So I really can't do anything with flash until I buy Adobe Flash, Clickteam Fusion, or Game Maker. Technically anything that lets me create Flash applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a free `mxmlc` compiler to build ActionScript into swf files. It can be downloaded with [Apache Flex SDK](http://flex.apache.org/)

And also a free IDE to work with Flash [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)

Comment: Okay, but I'm looking for something online,  since I am using a chromebook.

Comment: @Alobex you're going to need to download and install applications to do any kind of serious development, so your chromebook isn't going to be enough